# twitter - request token failing

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have been toying around with the twitter API over the last few days, but seem to be stuck at requesting a "request token". (flow A)

[image]

Over at the twitter api, I should be hitting the following end point (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token) and on a successful request this should net me an `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_callback_confirmed` (should match what I pass). I attempted to just use my private key, but this of course is failing. Is my understanding of how to generate this request wrong?

I believe my issue is the way I am generating the `oauth_signature`. Reading the documentation at twitter, everything seems straight forward until I need to generate signing key documented [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures#getting-a-signing-key). It states that the signing key should be `Consumer Secret` & `OAuth token secret`, but to me this is a circular reference. The response, for this request, should contain the `oauth_token_secret`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this request an *empty* `oauth_token_secret` is expected. Signing key should be `consumer_secret&`, the trailing `&` must be included.

Relevant quote from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.2:

> An "&" character (ASCII code 38), which MUST be included
> even when either secret is empty.

Comment: Thank you @pii_ke I completely missed that.